# Get Value(XPath) using XSL Variable - xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

While trying to parse the below `xml`,

```
<root>
<SelectValue>One</SelectValue> <!-- Tends to Vary -->
<SubRoot>  <!-- Iterate elements inside it using [ SelectValue] -->
    <One>One</One>
    <Two>Two</Two>
    <Three>Three</Three> 
</SubRoot>
</root>
```

with below `xsl`,

```
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:variable name="columns" select="SelectValue"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="SubRoot"> -->
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="SubRoot/@*[local-name()=$columns]"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

  </xsl:for-each>
```

Retrieves an empty `html-tags` while i expect something like below,

```
 <table>
   <thead>
   <th>One</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
    </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to pass the value inside `<SelectValue>` to get the nodes inside `<SubRoot>`

Any thoughts here ?

Comment: Is that the full and exact error message you get?

Comment: Nope. Its the the error message i got from another question and solved the error by removing `$` while defining it

Comment: Please always quote the exact and full error message that **you** get.

Comment: I think you need to add the expected output, and explain in a few words what are you trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recognize the error message you quote (it doesn't even seem to be English), but I do get an error when trying to run your code. The reason is that your variable name is invalid; you need to change:

```
<xsl:variable name="$columns" select="..."/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:variable name="columns" select="..."/>
```

Use the `$` prefix when referring to the variable, not when defining it.

---

Note also that an XPath expression beginning with a `/`is an *absolute path*, starting at the root node. Therefore none of your `select` expressions - with the exception of `/root` - will select anything. I am guessing you are trying to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="SelectValue"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="SubRoot/*[local-name()=$columns]"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

which given your input example will return:

```
<tr>
  <td>One</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and as you u said it doesnt select anything. Updated my ques , Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Within xsl:for-each select="SubRoot", the SubRoot is the context node, so you should not be selecting down to a further SubRoot. So you want

```
<xsl:for-each select="SubRoot">
     <tr>
          <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@*[local-name()=$columns]"/>
          </td>
    </tr>
```